# Is there another way to apply CSS on the last child element without using the :last-child class?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I am wondering if there's another way using CSS to style the last child element without the use of the `:last-child` pseudo class? For example, here is my HTML code:

```
<div>
    <div class="someText">
        <p>Some text about Biology</p>
    </div>
    <div class="someText">
        <p>Some text about Math</p>
    </div>
    <div class="someText">
        <p>Some text about Environmental Science</p>
    </div>
    <div class="someText">
        <p>Some text about physics</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Let's say I want to change the text color on the last someText element to blue. This is my CSS:

```
.someText p{
    color: green;
}

.someText:last-child p{
    color: blue
}
```

While this works, I am wondering if there is a way to style the last element without using pseudo class?

I am asking because I want to remove the `<div>` from my HTML that is wrapping the `someText` classes.

Basically how would I apply the CSS to the last child if the my HTML instead looked like this:

```
<div class="someText">
    <p>Some text about Biology</p>
</div>
<div class="someText">
    <p>Some text about Math</p>
</div>
<div class="someText">
    <p>Some text about Environmental Science</p>
</div>
<div class="someText">
    <p>Some text about physics</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can try `.someText:last-of-type` [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type). Though I'm a bit confused what you're trying to achieve because those `someText` elements are almost certainly going to be wrapped in some parent element like `<body>`, even if you don't explicitly do it

Comment: If one of the elements is somehow special and you need to style it differently add a class to it that you can target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:last-of-type` may not be suitable here since that means you cannot have another `<div>` after your HTML code in the same level, even with a different class name.

You may consider combining [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo class to mimic `:last-of-class`. But pay attention that [`:has()` hasn't been widely supported yet](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas).

```css
.someText:not(:has(~ .someText))
```

```css
.someText p {
    color: green;
}

.someText:not(:has(~ .someText)) p {
    color: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="someText">
    <p>Some text about Biology</p>
</div>
<div class="someText">
    <p>Some text about Math</p>
</div>
<div class="someText">
    <p>Some text about Environmental Science</p>
</div>
<div class="someText">
    <p>Some text about physics</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Some irrelevant text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do two ways i am here attaching my pen look into it.

```
.someText:last-of-type p {

    enter code here.     

}
```

https://codepen.io/fbarun/pen/LYXvBpo

Answer (score -1):

The pseudo class that you're looking for is `:last-of-type`

```
.someText:last-of-type {
    color: blue;
}
```

This will make the last `someText` element blue.